# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'passport')

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm currently doing a project that will need me to show my users profiles from database but I encounter a problem. I'm using expressjs and mongoDB as my database.  I will be grateful for a solutions here.

below are my code from my server.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

function connectDB() {
    try{
        console.log("connection to db")
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db')
        console.log("connected")
    } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
    }
}
connectDB()
const User = require('./model/reguser')

let foundUser

app.post('/login', async (req, res)=>{
    const {username, password} = req.body
    foundUser = await User.findOne({username:username})

    if(foundUser){
        const user = await bcrypt.compare(password, foundUser.password)
        if (user){
            res.redirect('/')
        }else{
            req.flash('info', 'Username or Password incorrect')
            res.redirect('/login')
        }
    }else{
        const foundAdmin = await Admin.findOne({username:username})
        if(foundAdmin){
            const user = await bcrypt.compare(password, foundAdmin.password)
            if(user){
                res.redirect('/admin')
            }else{
                req.flash('info', 'Username or Password incorrect')
                res.redirect('/login')
            } 
        }
    }
})

app.get('/', (req, res )=>{
    res.render('dashboard.ejs', {foundUser})
})
```

below is the code of my schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const users = new Schema ({
    username:{
        type:String,
        unique: true,
        trim:true,
        minlength:[10, 'Username must be more than 10'],
        required: true
    },
    
    password:{
        type:String,
        required: true,
        trim:true,
        minlength:[10, 'Password must be more than 8']        
    },

    fullname:{
        type:String,
        required: true,
        trim:true,
        minlength:[10, 'Fullname must be more than 8']
        
    },

    passport:{
        type:String,
        required: true,
        trim:true,
        minlength:[10, 'Passport must be more than 8']        
    },

    phone:{
        type:String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim:true,
        minlength:[10, 'Phone be more than 8']
        
    },

    role:String,
    active:Boolean
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', users);
```

but I do get this error message.

```
TypeError: C:\Users\go\Downloads\mongo-class\views\dashboard.ejs:117
    115|         <div class="profile">

    116|           

 >> 117|           <div><img src=<%= foundUser.passport %>  alt=<%= foundUser.fullname %>></div>

    118|           <div class="fullname"><p><%=foundUser.fullname %></p></div>

    119|           <div class="phone"><p><%= foundUser.phone %></p></div>

    120|           <div class="name"><p><%=foundUser.email %></p></div>


Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'passport')
    at eval ("C:\\Users\\go\\Downloads\\mongo-class\\views\\dashboard.ejs":13:36)
    at dashboard (C:\Users\go\Downloads\mongo-class\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:703:17)
    at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\go\Downloads\mongo-class\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\go\Downloads\mongo-class\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (C:\Users\go\Downloads\mongo-class\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\go\Downloads\mongo-class\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\go\Downloads\mongo-class\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\go\Downloads\mongo-class\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at C:\Users\go\Downloads\mongo-class\app.js:139:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\go\Downloads\mongo-class\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: I guess this "const foundAdmin = await Admin.findOne({username:username})" is returning 'undefined' ?

Comment: try to `console.log(foundUser)` the data of `foundUser = await User.findOne({username:username})`;

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do when you get that error message? are you trying to login as admin or  are you  using a known user credentials?  In you .ejs file  you should first check that foundUser is not null or undefined before using it's properties. for example:

```
<% if (foundUser) { %>
  <div>
    <img src="<%= foundUser.passport %>" alt="<%= foundUser.fullname %>">
  </div>
<% } else { %>
  <div>
    <p>User information not available.</p>
  </div>
<% } %>
```